# How to add drop shadow in uicollectionview using swift?

Tags: swift

I want to add drop shadow in uicollectionview. CollectionView is just covering half of screen, So want to add drop shadow on bottom.

Comment: You want shadow in collection view or collection view cell?

Comment: I want shadow in collection view.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will make a drop shadow at the bottom of the UICollectionView

```
myCollection.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
myCollection.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1)
myCollection.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
myCollection.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
myCollection.clipsToBounds = false
myCollection.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Note that `UICollectionView` is initialized with the following by default:

```
clipsToBounds = true 
layer.masksToBounds = true
```

and you must set them to `false` otherwise the shadow will not be displayed.

Comment: thanks. this works. but i also want to add a shadow on the right side of my view. what should i do for that?